# Python Sin Cos Tan cannot find txt.display (Calculator)

Tags: python, tkinter

The calculator cannot find `txtDisplay`

I've tried everything

```py
from tkinter import*
import math

cal = Tk()
cal.title("Calculator")
operator= ""
text_Input = StringVar()

textDisplay = Entry(cal, font=('fixedsys', 20, 'bold'), textvariable=text_Input, bd=30, insertwidth=4,
                    bg='Orange', justify='right').grid(columnspan=4)


def btnClick(number):
    global operator
    operator = operator + str(number)
    text_Input.set(operator)

def btnClear():
    global opderator
    operator=''
    text_Input.set('')

def btnEquals():
    global operator
    result = str(eval(operator))
    text_Input.set(result)
    operator=''

class Calc():
    def __init__(self):
        self.total=0
        self.total=""
        self.input_value = True
        self.check_sum = False
        self.op = ""
        self.result = False

    def display(self, value):
        txtDisplay.delete(0, END)
        txtDisplay.insert(0, value)

    def btnsin(self):
        self.result = False
        self.current = math.sin(float(txtDisplay.get()))
        self.display(self.current)

    def btncos(self):
        self.result = False
        self.current = math.cos(float(txtDisplay.get()))
        self.display(self.current)

    def btntan(self):
        self.result = False
        self.current = math.tan(float(txtDisplay.get()))
        self.display(self.current)



added_value = Calc()

#SIN, COS AND TAN BUTTONS
btnsin=Button(cal, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, fg='white', font=('fixedsys', 20, 'bold'),
            text='Sin', bg='Blue', command=added_value.btnsin).grid(row=1, column=0)

btncos=Button(cal, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, fg='white', font=('fixedsys', 20, 'bold'),
            text='Cos', bg='Blue', command=added_value.btncos).grid(row=1, column=1)

btntan=Button(cal, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, fg='white', font=('fixedsys', 20, 'bold'),
            text='Tan', bg='Blue', command=added_value.btntan).grid(row=1, column=2)

#Buttons

btn7=Button(cal, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, fg='white', font=('fixedsys', 20, 'bold'),
            text='7', bg='Blue', command=lambda:btnClick(7)).grid(row=2, column=0)

btn8=Button(cal, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, fg='white', font=('fixedsys', 20, 'bold'),
            text='8', bg='Blue', command=lambda:btnClick(8)).grid(row=2, column=1)

btn9=Button(cal, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, fg='white', font=('fixedsys', 20, 'bold'),
            text='9', bg='Blue', command=lambda:btnClick(9)).grid(row=2, column=2)

btnAdd=Button(cal, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, fg='white', font=('fixedsys', 20, 'bold'),
            text='+', bg='Blue', command=lambda:btnClick('+')).grid(row=2, column=3)

#MoreButtons

btn4=Button(cal, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, fg='white', font=('fixedsys', 20, 'bold'),
            text='4', bg='Blue', command=lambda:btnClick(4)).grid(row=3, column=0)

btn5=Button(cal, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, fg='white', font=('fixedsys', 20, 'bold'),
            text='5', bg='Blue', command=lambda:btnClick(5)).grid(row=3, column=1)

btn6=Button(cal, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, fg='white', font=('fixedsys', 20, 'bold'),
            text='6', bg='Blue', command=lambda:btnClick(6)).grid(row=3, column=2)

btnSub=Button(cal, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, fg='white', font=('fixedsys', 20, 'bold'),
            text='-', bg='Blue', command=lambda:btnClick('-')).grid(row=3, column=3)

#MoreButtons2

btn1=Button(cal, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, fg='black', font=('fixedsys', 20, 'bold'),
            text='1', bg='Yellow', command=lambda:btnClick(1)).grid(row=4, column=0)

btn2=Button(cal, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, fg='black', font=('fixedsys', 20, 'bold'),
            text='2', bg='Yellow', command=lambda:btnClick(2)).grid(row=4, column=1)

btn3=Button(cal, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, fg='black', font=('fixedsys', 20, 'bold'),
            text='3', bg='Yellow', command=lambda:btnClick(3)).grid(row=4, column=2)

btnTimes=Button(cal, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, fg='black', font=('fixedsys', 20, 'bold'),
            text='x', bg='Yellow', command=lambda:btnClick('*')).grid(row=4, column=3)

#MoreButtons3

btn0=Button(cal, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, fg='black', font=('fixedsys', 20, 'bold'),
            text='0', bg='Yellow', command=lambda:btnClick(0)).grid(row=5, column=0)

btnClear=Button(cal, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, fg='black', font=('fixedsys', 20, 'bold'),
            text='C', bg='Yellow', command=btnClear).grid(row=5, column=1)

btnEquals=Button(cal, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, fg='black', font=('fixedsys', 20, 'bold'),
            text='=', bg='Yellow', command=btnEquals).grid(row=5, column=2)

btnDivide=Button(cal, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, fg='black', font=('fixedsys', 20, 'bold'),
            text='/', bg='Yellow', command=lambda:btnClick('/')).grid(row=5, column=3)


#End Main Loop
cal.mainloop()
```

`txtDisplay` not found please help me python syntax error im new to python and need some assistance. Thanks.

Comment: `txtDisplay` and `textDisplay` are different variable names. Try to use only one or the other, not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to change the textDisplay to txtDisplay in the variable declaration (you've accidentally used both while referencing the same variable.)
Secondly, you should divide the creation of the variable and the positioning of it between two different commands, because by positioning it in the declaration command, (using the grid() command,) you can't reference the variable.

```
from tkinter import*
import math

cal = Tk()
cal.title("Calculator")
operator= ""
text_Input = StringVar()

txtDisplay = Entry(cal, font=('fixedsys', 20, 'bold'), textvariable=text_Input, bd=30, insertwidth=4,
                    bg='Orange', justify='right')
txtDisplay.grid(columnspan=4)


def btnClick(number):
    global operator
    operator = operator + str(number)
    text_Input.set(operator)

def btnClear():
    global opderator
    operator=''
    text_Input.set('')

def btnEquals():
    global operator
    result = str(eval(operator))
    text_Input.set(result)
    operator=''

class Calc():
    def __init__(self):
        self.total=0
        self.total=""
        self.input_value = True
        self.check_sum = False
        self.op = ""
        self.result = False

    def display(self, value):
        txtDisplay.delete(0, END)
        txtDisplay.insert(0, value)

    def btnsin(self):
        self.result = False
        self.current = math.sin(float(txtDisplay.get()))
        self.display(self.current)

    def btncos(self):
        self.result = False
        self.current = math.cos(float(txtDisplay.get()))
        self.display(self.current)

    def btntan(self):
        self.result = False
        self.current = math.tan(float(txtDisplay.get()))
        self.display(self.current)



added_value = Calc()

#SIN, COS AND TAN BUTTONS
btnsin=Button(cal, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, fg='white', font=('fixedsys', 20, 'bold'),
            text='Sin', bg='Blue', command=added_value.btnsin).grid(row=1, column=0)

btncos=Button(cal, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, fg='white', font=('fixedsys', 20, 'bold'),
            text='Cos', bg='Blue', command=added_value.btncos).grid(row=1, column=1)

btntan=Button(cal, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, fg='white', font=('fixedsys', 20, 'bold'),
            text='Tan', bg='Blue', command=added_value.btntan).grid(row=1, column=2)

#Buttons

btn7=Button(cal, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, fg='white', font=('fixedsys', 20, 'bold'),
            text='7', bg='Blue', command=lambda:btnClick(7)).grid(row=2, column=0)

btn8=Button(cal, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, fg='white', font=('fixedsys', 20, 'bold'),
            text='8', bg='Blue', command=lambda:btnClick(8)).grid(row=2, column=1)

btn9=Button(cal, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, fg='white', font=('fixedsys', 20, 'bold'),
            text='9', bg='Blue', command=lambda:btnClick(9)).grid(row=2, column=2)

btnAdd=Button(cal, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, fg='white', font=('fixedsys', 20, 'bold'),
            text='+', bg='Blue', command=lambda:btnClick('+')).grid(row=2, column=3)

#MoreButtons

btn4=Button(cal, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, fg='white', font=('fixedsys', 20, 'bold'),
            text='4', bg='Blue', command=lambda:btnClick(4)).grid(row=3, column=0)

btn5=Button(cal, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, fg='white', font=('fixedsys', 20, 'bold'),
            text='5', bg='Blue', command=lambda:btnClick(5)).grid(row=3, column=1)

btn6=Button(cal, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, fg='white', font=('fixedsys', 20, 'bold'),
            text='6', bg='Blue', command=lambda:btnClick(6)).grid(row=3, column=2)

btnSub=Button(cal, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, fg='white', font=('fixedsys', 20, 'bold'),
            text='-', bg='Blue', command=lambda:btnClick('-')).grid(row=3, column=3)

#MoreButtons2

btn1=Button(cal, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, fg='black', font=('fixedsys', 20, 'bold'),
            text='1', bg='Yellow', command=lambda:btnClick(1)).grid(row=4, column=0)

btn2=Button(cal, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, fg='black', font=('fixedsys', 20, 'bold'),
            text='2', bg='Yellow', command=lambda:btnClick(2)).grid(row=4, column=1)

btn3=Button(cal, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, fg='black', font=('fixedsys', 20, 'bold'),
            text='3', bg='Yellow', command=lambda:btnClick(3)).grid(row=4, column=2)

btnTimes=Button(cal, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, fg='black', font=('fixedsys', 20, 'bold'),
            text='x', bg='Yellow', command=lambda:btnClick('*')).grid(row=4, column=3)

#MoreButtons3

btn0=Button(cal, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, fg='black', font=('fixedsys', 20, 'bold'),
            text='0', bg='Yellow', command=lambda:btnClick(0)).grid(row=5, column=0)

btnClear=Button(cal, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, fg='black', font=('fixedsys', 20, 'bold'),
            text='C', bg='Yellow', command=btnClear).grid(row=5, column=1)

btnEquals=Button(cal, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, fg='black', font=('fixedsys', 20, 'bold'),
            text='=', bg='Yellow', command=btnEquals).grid(row=5, column=2)

btnDivide=Button(cal, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, fg='black', font=('fixedsys', 20, 'bold'),
            text='/', bg='Yellow', command=lambda:btnClick('/')).grid(row=5, column=3)


#End Main Loop
cal.mainloop()
```